# Can adId/privacy APIs in Android API 34 be used in product apps?

Tags: android

Several adId APIs are published in Android API 34, such as AdIdManager, (https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/reference/adservices/adid/AdIdManager). However, when AdIdManager::getAdId(...) is called, I get error "Caller is not authorized to call this API. Caller is not allowed". To avoid it, I have to use adb command to add my app to the allow-list, but no other way to allow it. I am wondering if these APIs are good enough to be used. Why are they published in stable release if not yet or no way to enable it programmatically? Could we use adb command to enable it on each device which runs my app?

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox and specifically https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/release-notes showing that those APIs are part of a not production ready program.

Comment: not production ready program. Why is AdIdManager added in API level 34 (https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/reference/adservices/adid/AdIdManager) ?

Comment: Speculation: the API may be set but the backend / device services are not. If you've seen: https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup-device-access?version=beta#enable-access you'll see that the expectation is for some type of end user control UI be available when the Privacy Sandbox goes general availability.